# Can Azure Active Directory be used as a Login Broker?

Tags: c#, security, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

My company wants to develop something it calls a "**Login Broker**" for an on-premise **desktop** application also under development.  The on-premise application will make significant use of Azure services (**DocumentDb**, **Table Storage**, **Service Fabric**, etc).  Our goal is to be able to distribute the main application without it containing any knowledge of configuration values to reach Azure resources (endpoints, keys, etc).  As a user logs in through the Login Broker, the desktop application then becomes aware of how to reach its resources, what permissions that user has within the application, and so on.

So far, my research has taken me in the direction of **claims-based authentication** (I'm very new to this area), which sounds correct in concept.  Once a user logs in, the claims that we want to put into a token would be those specifics I mentioned above, plus we will undoubtedly have other claims that we don't know of yet that we want to assert.

My question is, does my company need to develop a custom login service / broker to authenticate users and deliver a configuration payload, or **can Azure Active Directory serve this need in the way I described?**  Is this the kind of thing that AAD is suited for natively or would this wind up being a shoehorn that we'd rather avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described looks like the federated identity, locally Microsoft has the Active Directory Federation Services, in cloud there are a few options:

1) Azure AD Access Control Services - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-identity/#ac

2) Azure AD B2C - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/

I would recommend to take a look at the Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Azure AD B2C looks very promising and I intend to explore that topic further.  However, since I posted my question, another resource mentioned that from my WPF application I could use ADAL to authenticate access to a .NET Web API application, store and manage refresh tokens using DPAPI.

What are the major benefits  or drawbacks of one approach over the other?

Comment: Good question. I would say that AD B2C is more high level for the developer than your approach, which is good, but i would say that the developer should do a lot of research and development. Either way, you should be able to get what you want, it is just a matter of abstraction.